# Customising ApplicationUser asp.net-identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add a list of objects the the standard ApplicationUser object in MVC.

I've been looking at dozens of questions all about this but they all seem to be adding a single object, rather than a list.

What I'm trying to do is record all historic passwords a user has used, so I've added a table called `AspNetUserPreviousPassword`.

In my code I've added this line to the `ApplicationUser`class:

```
public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserPreviousPassword> PreviousUserPasswords { get; set; }
```

and within the `AspNetUserPreviousPassword` object I've added the following:

```
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

I've created the following extensions class:

public static class IdentityExtensions which has appeared in the `User.Identity` intellisense - so far so good.

```
{
    public static string GetPreviousUserPasswords(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("PreviousUserPasswords");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

When I went to edit the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` function, to insert the custom claims, I began to think my approach was incorrect as you can only add strings, e.g.

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("PreviousUserPasswords", "This must be a string"));
```

Despite only being able to add a string here, I wanted to test my previous passwords were being read from the database so I added this code to test:

```
string previousPasswords = "";
await this.PreviousUserPasswords.ForEachAsync(p => previousPasswords += p.PasswordHash);
```

`this.PreviousUserPasswords` is always `NULL`.

My questions:

1) Why is `this.PreviousUserPasswords` always `NULL`?

2) Is my approach even correct - can I add a list of objects to `ApplicationUser` or should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article I used to get preventing the use of previous "X" passwords in my implementation of Asp.Net Identity. I tweaked it to suit my needs but this got me everything I needed to get on the right track. Give it a read.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/how-to-customize-password-policy-in-Asp-Net-identity/

Comment: Cool I'll give it a read. I've pretty much implemented my own way of doing it but it isn't as clean as having the user contain the list of previous passwords but it seems to do the trick, so far anyway...

Comment: Works very well my me. I can each client set their own password policy requirements including defining a user cannot use there last "X" passwords. If this helps please mark as accepted answer ;)